# How can I set an alarm manager to be triggered when there is internet connection?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-api-levels, android-jobscheduler

I have used alarm manager to sound at a specific time or repeating on specific days but I can't seem to find a way to make it be triggered at a specific condition which is "on available network".

I need to do this because I'm using an intent in the manifest which triggers a background service, this works up until api23. When I wanted to do something similar for api > 23 I came to the conclusion that I can use either jobscheduler or alarm manager. I want to try both to see which is more useful to me in this specific case.

Comment: `AlarmManager` has nothing for network detection; it is purely driven by time.

Comment: I guessed as much since the official documentation didn't mention anything about another condition except for time

Comment: but whenever I searched for a replacement for declaring a connectivity intent in the manifest file, alarm manager always came up so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, at least I won't waste any more time searching for something that doesn't exist.